# 2 SXA sites on same Azure app service need different federated authentication providers

Tags: sxa, federated-authentication

I have 2 `SXA` sites running on the same Azure app service. Both sites require `Okta federated authentication (OIDC)`. Is it possible to have more than one `IdentityProvidersProcessor` (1 for each SXA site b/c each needs its own Okta application settings)?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can have more than one `IdentityProvidersProcessor` without making alot of customizations. However you could modify the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` in the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` event, they are on the `notification.Options` object. This event occurs before the user will get redirected to Okta, below an example:

```
args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async(notification) =>
        {
            //set the correct options depending on the site e.g.
            if(site1) {
                notification.Options.ClientId = "site 1 client id";
            } else {
                notification.Options.ClientId = "site 2 client id";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!