# Get current site in IdentityProvidersProcessor for Federated Login

Tags: sitecore-api, pipelines, federated-authentication, authentication

We have a multisite architecture, and I am working on implementing the federated authentication using Auth0 for visitors login/signup.
I need to fetch separate client id and secret per tenant based on the site. On the pipeline processor **IdentityProviderProcessor** (inherited from **IdentityProvidersProcessor**) I am unable to fetch the site name.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you use this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26878/2495 ?

Comment: @Jeroen thank you so much, that really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer isn't mine but posting in case anyone may need in future.
As per @Nehemiah from Sitecore slack:

> Nehemiah:
> I don't think so. I believe they are part of middleware where Sitecore context won't be there.

I followed the link mentioned by @Jeroen. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26878/3632
One small adjustment I had to make was, I assigned the clientId to
notification.ProtocolMessage.ClientId

In **RedirectToIdentityProvider**, the Sitecore.Context.Site becomes available.